# Rotate one character in string TextView Android

Tags: android, rotation

I'm learning Android and I have a problem when I try rotate one character in string TextView in Android, example string :"**v Magic Skin**" and I want to rotate character "**v**" 180 degrees. It's like magic skin in camera 360.

[camera 360](http://www.google.com.vn/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fkenhapk.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F09%2Fmagic-skin-trong-camera360.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fkenhapk.com%2Fung-dung%2Ftai-camera360.html&h=568&w=320&tbnid=WP0QEDtgEMViSM%3A&zoom=1&docid=6sYGhTIWglVdAM&ei=IU10VM7AF8728QWz_oGgCw&tbm=isch&ved=0CFoQMyg1MDU&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=312&page=3&start=46&ndsp=27) (sorry, i cant upload image because i haven't 10 reputation )

In camera360, when you hide or show toolbar " v Magic Skin". If you hide, "v" character will rotate 180 degrees. 
I search many solution rotate character like that but no result. Please can anyone help me and give me some example ????

P/S: my english not good

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing the text using canvas, then you can simply rotate the canavs and write the text and restore the canvas.

generic code

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint)
    {
        if (start >= end) {
            return;
        }
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(x, y);
        canvas.rotate(180);
        canvas.drawText("v", x1, y1, paint);
        canavs.restore();
        // draw rest of text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than rotate the text, you might put a picture of V and just when you want, replace the image in the image of V reversed.

Comment: I think rotate the text is the best